# Correct regex for a password-type field

Tags: regex, passwords

Working on password-field.

The regex expression for a field container letters (lowercase, uppercase), digits and some special characters will look like this:

```
^([a-z,A-Z,0-9,#,$,%,&,_,]{8,20})*$
```

Tell me please, how this should be modified if I want every pass phrase to have at least one lowercase, one uppercase and one digit?

For example, for 3-characters long pass it is:

- 'aB3' - pass
- 'ab3' - fail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use lookaheads and also you need to remove all the commas present inside the character class.

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?\d)[a-zA-Z0-9#$%&_]{8,20}$
```

Note that the password must be atleast 8 and atmost 20 chars long.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xP9dR0/2)

Answer (score 0):

**THIS ANSWER HAS BEEN ARCHIVED BECAUSE IT SUCKS.**

Use the `+` token, which tells the engine to attempt to find one or more of the preceding token. e.g:

```
^(?=[a-z]+)(?=[A-Z])+(?=[0-9])+(?=[#$%&_\,\.]*)$
```

Then, use a length check elsewhere in the code to verify length.

Comment: And it also forces ordering that is not intended in the question.

Comment: It's been modified to allow commas. You can take that out if you want.

Comment: Both problems have now been fixed.

Comment: Hey, I gave you plus. Thank you for participating ;-) We are all here to learn something new and contribute to community.